# Replication of files between a windows server and a NAS

Tags: replication, windows, network-attached-storage, dfs-r

I am planning some improvements to my server infrastructure and I have encountered a potential problem.

I currently use dfs replication to sync files between 3 windows servers at 3 different sites.

I am planning on getting a NAS box for one of the sites. How could I replicate files between the NAS and the windows servers? My guess is that DFS won't work unless I spend a lot on a NAS that runs windows server.

Are there any other options for syncing my files or do I need to stick with my original setup?

Comment: Robocopy? Sounds like a shopping question

Comment: Robocopy would be fine for initially getting the files to the NAS but I wasn't aware you could use it to sync the ongoing changes across all three sites?